The Tap 'Auto-Rig-Pro no longer has a function after Smart Rigging?

Link to the tutorial that I tried out: https://youtu.be/28gJhqCQyxE
[min. 2.07]
I would like to go to the 'Limb Options', but they are somehow no longer there...

That's a third-party addon, not part of Blender so you'll have to ask the developers that question as it's off-topic here.
